# redirect page using server's time, in 0-12 format

Tags: php

I have the following piece of code in php in order to redirect to different pages using the server's time. The problem is that server uses time 0-12 format and not 0-24. Any idea how to improve my code in order to work?

```
php?

  $timer=date('H:i:s');

  //redirect if hour between 8:00 to 21:00
  if(  ($timer > "08:00:00")  &&  ($timer < "21:00:00") ) {
    header('Location: index.php');
  }else{
    header('Location: logout.php');
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

`date('H')` is a 24 hour representation of the hour regradless of your timezone setting
`date('h')` is a 12 hour representation, or `date('g')` if you don't want a leading zero